# How to declare enum as a type?

Tags: java, enums

I am creating a **library**, which includes a function having argument as **enum**

```
public class Service
{
    public static void setServiceMode(SERVICE_MODE mode)
   {

   }
}
```

Now, I have a **project** which is importing the above library, and calling the "**setServiceMode**" function as follows

```
Service.setServiceMode(SERVICE_MODE.LOGIN)
```

My problem is that where to declare the enum (SERVICE_MODE), as I have to pass it in library function argument, and values to enum are project specific. **I don't want to make changes in my library**. How to achieve this in java ?

Comment: I don't understand your question ... how to declare the type? The type seems to be SERVICE_MODE

Comment: If you don't want the library to know the possible values of the enum, what sense does this all make?

Comment: I need this because I am hitting the asynchronous network hits with different SERVICE_MODES, from my project and need the response in the project after processing in the library. So my purpose is to get the response with enum service_mode that I passed while calling service from my project.

Comment: The important thing is, what will be the implementation of the method setServiceMode()? In other words, how will that method perform anything without any knowledge of the possible values of the SERVICE_MODE enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the library just accept *any* `enum` if that's acceptable:

```
public class Service {

    public static <E extends Enum<E>> void setServiceMode(E mode) {

    }

    // Or a pre-generics version.
    public static void setServiceMode2(Enum mode) {

    }
}

public enum SERVICE_MODE {

    LOGIN,
    LOGOUT;
}

public void test() {
    Service.setServiceMode(SERVICE_MODE.LOGIN);
    Service.setServiceMode2(SERVICE_MODE.LOGIN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SERVICE_MODE` will need to be contained in a library shared by both applications

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is to use interfaces where you need extensible enums. Here is an outline of the setup giving you the proper type constraints. In your library, define

```
interface ServiceMode<E extends Enum<E> & ServiceMode<E>> {}
```

and declare your posted method as

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & ServiceMode<E>> void setServiceMode(E mode) {}
```

In your client code, define an enum:

```
enum MyServiceMode implements ServiceMode<MyServiceMode> {}
```

The type bound on `ServiceMode` guarantees that it can only be parameterized by an enum which implements it and the additional constraint on the type passed to `setServiceMode` guarantees that it is a subtype of `ServiceMode` parameterized by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service class won't compile unless the SERVICE_MODE enum is in the classpath. Due to this strong dependency, the best idea is adding that enum to your library. If you cannot do this, then create a new library, which will be a dependency of yours.